# Finding the index of a string

Tags: string, delphi, search

I have a filter on a fileopen dialog

```
  Docs := 'Indscannet fil (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Indscannet fil (*.tif)|*.tif|' +
          'Word 2007 dokument (*.docx)|*.docx|Word 2003 dokument (*.doc)|*.doc|' +
          'PDF fil (*.pdf)|*.pdf|Alle filer (*.*)|*.*';
```

When I have selected a file, lets say it is called stack.pdf, I want to know that it was type 5 (jpg=1, tif=2, docx=3, doc=4, pdf=5)

How to do this in the easiest way?

The reason for all this is that the users almost always adds several documents of the same type and if this is a PDF I know that is number 5 in my filter and next time the user adds a file I can set dlgOpen.FilterIndex to 5e from the beginning so they won't have to select it each time. If it is 20 documents it might save a couple of minuttes.

Comment: @Blanktext That's for javascript, not Delphi

Comment: There are several interpretations of your question. You might just be asking how to know the type of a file, where simple `ExtractFileExt` will suffice and the whole "index of a string" bit is irrelevant. But you might wish to know how to get `5` from the input `stack.pdf`. That's quite a different question. Please edit your question to clarify what you're really asking for, and remove any information that isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: As @David Heffernan mentioned in his comment below `FilterIndex` does not always match actual file extension; So you shoud not use `FilterIndex` to determine file type. So, you have to extract file extension and use it;

You can define known file types enumeration like:

```
TKnowFiles = (kfUnknown, kfJpg, kfTif, ...)
```

You also can define their names like

```
const FilterNames = array[TKnownFiles] of string = ('Any file', ...);
```

then you can use RTTI functions `getEnumName/getEnumValue` to convert `kfJpg` to string representation and build `Filter` string at runtime. 
also using enumeration allows you to easily maintain and extend your code (what if you have to insert BMP files between tif and docx next week? docx, doc,pdf becoome 4,5,6 instead of 3,4,5 and you sould edit your code. )
one of possible solutions is:

```
type
    TKnownFileTypes = (kftUnknown, kftJpg, kftTif, kftDocx, kftDoc, kftPdf);
const
    FileFilterNames : array[TKnownFileTypes] of string = (
                            'Alle filer',
                            'Indscannet fil',
                            'Indscannet fil',
                            'Word 2007 dokument',
                            'Word 2003 dokument',
                            'PDF fil');

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const KnownFiles = [low(TKnownFileTypes) .. high(TKnownFileTypes)];
var filterString : string;
    fext : string;
    kf : TKnownFileTypes;
    kfs : string;

    resultFileType : TKnownFileTypes;
begin
    for kf in KnownFiles - [kftUnknown] do begin
        kfs := getEnumName(typeinfo(TKnownFileTypes), ord(kf));
        Delete(kfs, 1, 3);
        LowerCase(kfs);

        FilterString := FilterString +
                        Format('%s (*.%s)|*.%s|', [FileFilterNames[kf], kfs, kfs]);

    end;
    FilterString := FilterString + Format('%s (*.*)|*.*', [FileFilterNames[kftUnknown]]);
    OpenDialog1.Filter := FilterString;

    if not OpenDialog1.Execute() then exit;

    fext := ExtractFileExt(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Delete(fext, 1,1); //delete .dot
    fext := 'kft' + fExt;

    resultFileType := kftUnknown;
    for kf in KnownFiles - [kftUnknown] do begin
        kfs := getEnumName(typeinfo(TKnownFileTypes), ord(kf));
        kfs := LowerCase(kfs);
        if kfs <> fext then continue;

        resultFileType := kf;
    end;

    ShowMessage(Format('File Type: %s', [FileFilterNames[resultFileType]]));
end;
```

Comment: "If FilterIndex is less than 6, you can use it". No, you can still select a file that does not have an extension matching the other filters. All the filter index property tells is what the filter was set to. It gives no concrete information about the selected file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan then he has to extract file extension and determine file type manually, like in second code example, wich does not use `FilterIndex` property (ps: how to select jpg file in open dialog when PDF filter is selected?)

Comment: Type * into the filename text box and press enter. Then you can select anything in that folder.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan wow :) Didn't know that :) I should edit my post and delete first part with `filterIndex`

Comment: I quite often use that technique to cutdown a broad filter. For example, one of my app's filters has 5 or 6 extensions in it. But if I only want to select one of them, rather than using the mouse to click on the filter and so on. I'll just type *.txt, ENTER and then I am good to go. I don't really like the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ExtractFileExt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFileExt) to extract the file extension from the full path.

Or use `openDialog.FilterIndex` property to get the index of selected filter (5 for pdf in your case).

Comment: I would also use `if SameText(ExtractFileExt(OpenDialog1.FileName), '.ext') then ...` which will ignore case sensitivity of the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

```
function ExtensionIndex(const aFilter, aFile: string): integer;
var
  List: TStringList;
  Buffer: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  Key: string;
  fExt: string;
begin
  Result := - 1;
  i := 0;
  List := TStringList.Create;
  List.LineBreak := '|';
  List.Text := aFilter;
  Buffer := TStringList.Create;
  Buffer.Sorted := False;
  try
    while i < List.Count do
      begin
        inc(i);
        Key := AnsiLowerCase(List[i]);
        inc(i);
        Buffer.Add(Key);
      end;
    fExt := AnsiLowerCase(ExtractFileExt(aFile));
    for i := 0 to Buffer.Count - 1 do
      if Buffer[i] = '*' + fExt  then
        begin
          Result := i + 1;
          exit;
      end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Buffer);
    FreeAndNil(List);
  end;
end;
```

This does the trick for me.